# GWT and Ext-GWT: comparision

Tags: gwt, gxt

What's the advantage of EXT GWT compare to GWT? I have some experience in GWT. Now I want to learn some dynamic web GUI. I am wondering which one is more powerful or flexibile?

Comment: "Thanks" for closing a perfectly good and interesting question. 
When will Stackoverflow stop the question closing madness? 
This guy had a legitimate question and needs ANSWERS, not rude & alienating moderation. 
So what if it's a bit subjective? Most non-textbook and un-Googleable questions are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext GWT is an library for GWT, which brings in more widgets. GWT widgets are virtually only those plain HTML one, not much rich widgets. For other widget libraries you can also check SmartGWT, which is on LGPL, which means you can use it in commercial applications. Ext GWT is on GPL or commercial, which means you need either buy or make you app available on GPL.